# mottie tablesorter define secondary sort for a user selected column

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

How can you define a secondary sort for a user selected column using mottie jquery tablesorter?

https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/

Using sortList I am able to add an initial sort to the table with a defined secondary sort but how can I do the same for user selected columns.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but maybe you are looking for the [`sortAppend` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortappend)?

Comment: Thanks @Mottie the sortAppend option is what I am looking for